# I want to store date in my database table in dd/mm/yy format & perform order by on that column

Tags: database, date

I want to store date in my database table in dd/mm/yy format & perform order by on that column. Please help.

Comment: What is your database system and version?  SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle??

Comment: which database (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.)?

Answer (score 4):

A date field is not *stored* in any particular human readable format, rather that is how it is *formatted* when printed/displayed. `ORDER BY`  will properly sort a date/datetime column regardless of how you may want it formatted for display.